# Can I setup an AWS instance to stop itself without outside servers and tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

There are a good number of AWS instances that just don't need to run all the time. Among these are developer, test and bastion instances. It's reasonable to stop them when they're not in use to get a reasonable cost-savings.

For now I'm thinking of a simple mechanism to have a machine stop itself in the wee hours of the night when we know that it's very unlikely that they're in use. Bonus points for a reasonable way of stopping them after some period of inactivity.

To keep devops effort low I'd love to have something I can automatically install into a crontab when building the instance rather than something that I have to setup every time we spin up a new dev, test or bastion instance.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Is this an unreasonable / uninteresting question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Simplified based upon Mark's correct answer below.*

To have an instance stop itself at midnight every night drop this into your crontab:

```
0 0 * * * sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: You really don't need to go through all that. You literally just need to run a single command: `sudo shutdown -h now`.

Comment: Mark B - LOL thanks - that's a really good point! I think my approach is tainted by the fact that I started with the idea of doing this from a central server and handle this kind of policy via tag. Similar to what John mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having an instance stop itself, many AWS users create a *Stoppinator* app that regularly looks at EC2 instances, then **uses their tags to determine when to start/stop the instances**.

For example, you could tag a machine to turn on at 8am on weekdays and turn off at 10pm on weekdays. The *Stoppinator* could be a **Lambda function running on a 15-minute schedule** that checks the tags and takes appropriate action.

This way, you don't need to run any code on the actual instances -- you merely add a tag. You could even code a **default behaviour** that says "If there is no Stoppinator tag and no indication to keep the instance running 24x7, then stop it at 8pm by default."

Comment: Thanks John - yeah I referred to the use of tags in my response as well as a centralized service. We're dealing with a very small number of instances allowing the node to turn itself off without additional moving parts but I can see us moving in this direction as things get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Cloudwatch alarms to monitors activity of the ec2 instance. Parameters such as the **ComparisonOperator, Period, and Threshold** can be modified depending on how you want to monitor the instance.

Then, you can set up an SQS queue and set a Python Lambda function as its target. Within the lambda function, you can use boto to turn off the ec2 instance.

You can find a detailed guide here:
https://medium.com/geekculture/automatically-turn-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-31fedd363cad

Terraform setup:

https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800